# Comparison on std::tuple with multiple empty members doesn't compile on GCC

Tags: c++, g++, c++14

When there are multiple structures with no members in a tuple, trying to compile a comparison of tuples on GCC results in following error:

```
<source>: In function 'bool foo()':
<source>:120:16: error: request for member 'operator<' is ambiguous
  120 |     return a < b;
      |                ^
<source>:46:10: note: candidates are: 'bool N::operator<(const N&) const'
   46 |     bool operator<(const N &) const noexcept {
      |          ^~~~~~~~
<source>:46:10: note:                 'bool N::operator<(const N&) const'
Compiler returned: 1
```

Strangely enough, when I tie the same types I use in the tuple, it works as expected. One empty structure is also OK, two with different types are not.

Compilation with clang or msvc passes and yields expected results.

Is this correct behaviour, or is it a GCC/libstdc++ bug?

## Demo

([Try it](https://godbolt.org/z/NLrhZn), uncomment the desired testcase first)

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct A {
    int value;
    A(int value) : value(value) {}

    bool operator==(const A &other) const noexcept {
        return value == other.value;
    }

    bool operator!=(const A &other) const noexcept {
        return value != other.value;
    }

    bool operator<(const A &other) const noexcept {
        return value < other.value;
    }
};

struct N {
    bool operator==(const N &) const noexcept {
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const N &) const noexcept {
        return false;
    }

    bool operator<(const N &) const noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};

struct M {
    bool operator==(const M &) const noexcept {
        return true;
    }

    bool operator!=(const M &) const noexcept {
        return false;
    }

    bool operator<(const M &) const noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};



using AAKey = std::tuple<A, A>;
using ANAKey = std::tuple<A, N, A>;
using ANANKey = std::tuple<A, N, A, N>;
using ANAMKey = std::tuple<A, N, A, M>;
using NKey = std::tuple<N>;
using NNKey = std::tuple<N, N>;
using NMKey = std::tuple<N, M>;

bool foo() {
    /* Works
    AAKey a{0, 1};
    AAKey b{0, 0};
    //*/

    /* Works
    ANAKey a{0, N{}, 1};
    ANAKey b{0, N{}, 0};
    //*/

    /* Fails
    ANANKey a{0, N{}, 0, N{}};
    ANANKey b{0, N{}, 1, N{}};
    //*/

    /* Fails
    ANAMKey a{0, N{}, 0, M{}};
    ANAMKey b{0, N{}, 1, M{}};
    //*/


    /* Works
    NKey a{N{}};
    NKey b{N{}};
    //*/

    /* Fails
    NNKey a{N{}, N{}};
    NNKey b{N{}, N{}};
    //*/

    /* Fails
    NMKey a{N{}, M{}};
    NMKey b{N{}, M{}};
    //*/

    // Tying ANANKey into tuple:
    /* Works
    A ax1{0}, ay1{0}, ax2{0}, ay2{1};
    N nx1, ny1, nx2, ny2;
    auto a = std::tie(ax1, nx1, ax2, nx2);
    auto b = std::tie(ay1, ny1, ay2, ny2);
    //*/

    return a < b;
}
```

## EDIT

Extenal operator overloads actually work (thanks to @Turtlefight):

```cpp
#include <tuple>

struct O {
    friend bool operator==(const O &, const O &) noexcept {
        return true;
    }

    friend bool operator!=(const O &, const O &) noexcept {
        return false;
    }

    friend bool operator<(const O &, const O &) noexcept {
        return false;
    }
};

using OOKey = std::tuple<O, O>;

bool foo() {
    OOKey a{O{}, O{}};
    OOKey b{O{}, O{}};

    return a < b;
}
```

Comment: I'd say the fact that both candidates are the same function makes it pretty obvious this is a bug..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Also the `NMKey` case gives two different candidate functions: `bool N::operator<(const N&) const` and `bool M::operator<(const M&) const`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to happen on clang. Adding a [single member `int dummy;`](https://godbolt.org/z/JXiTNc), or using [external `operator<` overloads](https://godbolt.org/z/hV6LLa) seems to fix it. Maybe a compiler bug?

Comment: @Turtlefight Indeed the external overloads work, which is a workaround I can use, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a bug, in the sense that the standard doesn't give permission for the comparison to not work.

The cause is more interesting. libstdc++'s tuple is EBO'd in such a way that `tuple<N>` is actually derived from `N` if `N` is an empty class. When you do `a < b` we need to do a nonmember and a member lookup for `operator<`. The nonmember lookup finds `tuple`'s `operator<` as expected.

This member lookup, however, finds `operator<` in two different bases, so by [[class.member.lookup]p6-7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#6) this lookup produces an invalid set and is ill-formed on the spot.

Clang seems to accept this code by suppressing the error in the member lookup, but I'm not currently seeing anything in the standard that permits this behavior.

Comment: Great analysis, thank you. Would there be any other means to circumvent the lookup, or is the clang's solution/hack the only one?

Comment: As the library user, using hidden friends is the simplest fix.